# How to include an HTML download link to a local file in the server function in Shiny?

Tags: html, r, shiny

I have an app that essentially needs to have links to download several different PDFs that are stored locally in a `www` folder. I have been able to figure out how to generate this link in the UI.R file but I need to do this in the server and am struggling a bit with the HTML.

In the UI file, I just use a simple

```
tags$a(href='Incarceration rate graph.pdf', target='blank', 'Incarceration', download = 'Incarceration rate graph.pdf')
```

and this downloads the required file. However I try replicating this in the server function with the following minimal app

```
library(shiny)

setwd("//ace/home/anambiar/PDF download test")

ui <- fluidPage(
htmlOutput("test1")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
output$test1 <- renderUI({
  HTML("<a href='Incarceration rate graph.pdf' target = 'blank' download='Incarceration rate graph.pdf'> Incarceration rate </a>")
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

With this app, I get an error while downloading that says "Failed - no file" even though the actual HTML through the inspect element looks to almost exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h1("Test"),
  downloadLink('downloadData', 'Download'),
  selectizeInput("files", "Select Files", choices = c("File A", "File B", "File C"), selected = "File A", multiple = FALSE)
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('data-', input$files, "-", Sys.Date(), '.pdf', sep='')
    },
    content = function(file) {
      file.copy(paste0(input$files, ".pdf"), file)
    }
  )



}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here is a dynamic way to download your data.

Comment: Ah crap is this the only way? My final app will have about 50 links so I was hoping I didn't have to use downloadHandlers for each of them.

Comment: You can use a single downloadHandler to provide different files based on a previous selection. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49061057/create-downloadbutton-that-can-output-multiple-file-types-r-shiny)

Comment: why not zip your files? You could use a single downloadhandler for this.

Comment: @DSGym I can't zip them because their about 2 gigs in size total. I want to give the user the option of which file to download.

Comment: updated the code. Does this suit your needs? If yes, I´m happy if you accept the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate 50 links I would suggest you take a look at [Modularizing Shiny app code](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html). [Here](https://www.cultureofinsight.com/blog/2018/01/05/2017-11-13-reproducible-shiny-app-development-with-modules/) is another nice link that explains how to use `purrr` to generate multiple UI elements (`downloadLink`s in your case) starting from a vector (see section "Purrrifying Module Deployment").

Comment: I believe the "Here" link above is broken. [Here](https://www.blog.cultureofinsight.com/2018/01/reproducible-shiny-app-development-with-modules/) it is.